# SHA-256 support for SecretKeyFactory in Java 6 and 7?

Tags: key-derivation, sha-256, pbkdf-2

According to the following linked Java documentation, the relevant option for SecretKeyFactory algorithm (ignoring deprecated options involving MD5 or DES etc.) running in [JRE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) and [JRE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) is: **PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1**

With the advent of SHAttered, does Oracle have any plan to support later SHA versions for SecretKeyFactory? What are the alternatives?

Comment: a) HMAC-SHA1 is still fine, b) password-hashing doesn't need to have collision resistance, it is trivial to construct a collision with PBKDF2 for all hashes.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SecretKeyFactory

Answer (score 2):

> With the advent of SHAttered, does Oracle have any plan to support
>   later SHA versions for SecretKeyFactory?

First, they don't need to. We are talking about PBKDF with HMAC-SHA1 here, which is a password-based key derivation function.You don't need collision resistance (which is the only property SHAttered broke) for password hashing, [in fact it is trivial to find two passwords that hash to the same value with PBKDF2.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/15221/23623) What you really want from a password hash is one-way-ness / pre-image resistance (ie you can't recover the input from the output) other than using generic attacks.

Second, as of JRE8 you can use any pseudo-random function (PRF) the API knows instead of HMAC-SHA1 already and [in fact HMAC-SHA256 is given as  an example in the documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#SecretKeyFactory)

> What are the alternatives?

You don't use PBKDF2 from the standard library but rather use a binding to a more advanced password-based key derivation function such as [Argon2](https://github.com/P-H-C/phc-winner-argon2), [which has at least bindings for Java.](https://github.com/phxql/argon2-jvm)

Comment: From your comment, I understand that PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 is still safe for password hashing. By I intend to use it for communication as well. So I will check with Argon2 or other libraries.